# combining flipsideview and navigationview

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller, navigation, cocoa-design-patterns

when i am trying to combine flipsideview and navigation view i am getting following error
"request for member 'delegate' is something not in a structure or union" on the line `controller.delegate = self`;

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller's implementation, you can set the delegate of the UINavigationController through the property [navigationController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW44):

```
controller.navigationController.delegate = self;
```

This assumes that your view controller implements the [UINavigationControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

Also, I have found that it is easier to handle functionality related to view switching in [viewWillAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) and [viewWillDisappear:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW18) rather than implementing the above navigation protocol.